# Qtreewidgetitem with checkbox

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, qtreewidgetitem

A checkbox is added correctly when I set the check state of a qtreewidgetitem, but I´m not able to check/uncheck it in my qtreewidget. What am I doing wrong?

```
QTreeWidgetItem* item =
    new QTreeWidgetItem(parent);
item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable |
               Qt::ItemIsSelectable);
item->setText(0, text);
item->setCheckState(1, Qt::Checked);
```

Comment: The default flags for `QTreeWidgetItem` are these `Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled`, you probably don't need to call `setFlags()` here.

Comment: If that doesn't solve the issue we might need to see some more code, like how do you add your item to your `QTreeWidget`?

Comment: item->setCheckState(1, Qt::Checked); should be actually item->setCheckState(0, Qt::Checked);

Comment: You should post a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It's likely that you will actually fix the problem yourself while creating it.

Comment: @Xplatforms, the first argument is correct, because I want to establish the checkbox in the second column.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza, the parent variable used in the ítem constructor is the QTreeWidget.

Comment: If you want the tree to have 2 columns, then did you call `setColumnCount(2)` on the tree widget?